# Map is not load on my Simulator also not load in Default Maps app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, mapkit

I am facing a very strange issue in **iPhone simulator**.

I have used Map in my app and while I run my app on the simulator it's not loading and I can see just grid on the screen.

**My App Screen:**

[image]

**Default Maps App:**

[image]

Is there any setting or anything which helps me to see Map on the iPhone simulator?

**Note: I can get my current location and movement on my `MapView` but not able to see the visual view of the map on the screen.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a bit more context.  Show your code, any errors, MKMapview or Google's etc.

Comment: Try to reset simulator `Simulator->Reset content and settings`..

Comment: what is your deployment target version ?

Comment: I am using `MKMapview` and even i comment all my code still its not showing map on screen.

Comment: @NiravD Already done but still same issue.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya My deployment target is 9.0.

Comment: @CodeChanger which code you use ? please update your question with small snapcode .

Comment: @CodeChanger did you enable your google map service ?

Comment: see this ans if useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/39344300/4003548.

Comment: provided screen is my output screen.

Comment: @vaibhav current location is working fine I am getting current location but not seeing map on screen.Thats what i mention in my **Note**.

Comment: @CodeChanger then according to me its entirely depend upon the internet speed please check.

Comment: @vaibhav I am working with higher internet speed approx **10mbps** speed so may be that is not the barrier.

Comment: okay then some important links you need to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409049/iphone-mkmapview-the-map-can-t-load-completely, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355425/mkmapview-tiles-not-loaded-with-zoom, [**Apple forums**](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31064).